# how to compare a table in sys and uat and capture the changes in the records

Tags: hadoop

- Same table available in two regions and we need to compare and identify the changes to its records
- say table A is in sys and uat ,I want to compare sys.A and uat.A and capture the change between two regions

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take some time to follow the [Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Also provide us the relevant code you wrote for your question (You can also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: what regions are these ? are these hbsae if so please add corresponding tag  in the question.